# Where is the floating point problem in this C# financial calculation?

Tags: c#, algorithm, floating-accuracy

I receive a FIX message for a trade Allocation, where Price is given in *cents* (ZAR / 100), but commission is given in *Rands*.  These values are represented by the constants.  When I run this calculation, `commPerc1` shows a value of 0.099999999999999978, and `commPerc2` shows 0.1.  These values look to differ by x10, yet with the check of calculating back to *Rands*, both `commRands1` and `commRands2` show very similar values of 336.4831554 and 336.48315540000004 respectively.

```
private const double Price = 5708.91;
private const double Qty = 5894;
private const double AbsComm = 336.4831554;

static void Main()
{

    double commCents = AbsComm * 100;
    double commPerc1 = commCents / (Qty * Price) * 100;
    double commRands1 = (Qty * Price) * (commPerc1 / 100) / 100;

    double commPerc2 = (AbsComm / (Qty * (Price / 100))) * 100;
    double commRands2 = (Qty * Price) * (commPerc2 / 100) / 100;
}
```

**PLEASE NOTE:**
I am dealing with legacy code here where a conversion to decimal would involve several changes and QA, so right now I have to accept `double`.

Comment: Why the hell do you use `double` instead of `Decimal` for financial calculations?

Comment: Where do you see a 10x difference? `0.099... = 0.1`, what you're seeing is the effect of some floating point error, nothing special. `commPerc1` is equal to `commPerc2`, ignoring those insignificant errors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Don't** use `double` for financial calculations, use `decimal` instead. Floating point numbers are OK for physical, measured values, where the value is never exact anyway. But for financial calculations you're working with **exact** values, you can't afford errors due to floating point representations. That's what `decimal` is made for:

> The Decimal value type is appropriate for financial calculations requiring large numbers of significant integral and fractional digits and no round-off errors.

[(from MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx)

Answer (score 5):

The floating point problem is **everywhere**, because **all** of your values are of type `double`, which is a double-precision floating-point type, not a base-10 numeric type. (Hence, all calculations being performed are floating-point calculations.)

You should declare your variables [`decimal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/364x0z75.aspx) instead. That type is purposed precisely for financial calculations.

Answer (score 4):

> When I run this calculation, `commPerc1` shows a value of `0.099999999999999978`, and `commPerc2` shows `0.1`. These values look to differ by x10

**No they don't**. There is only an infinitely small (but existing) rounding difference between. As others have already noted, **you should never use floating point with calculations that demand absolute precision**. With floating point you always have rounding errors like this, and e.g. financial clients don't like missing or extra pennies/cents in their books.

Comment: Yeah, thanks.  In my head, I mistakenly rounded the 9 of the 0.09 to a 1, giving 0.01.

Answer (score 2):

That's due to the way floating numbers are stored in memory. You could use `decimal` instead of `double` or `float` when dealing with financial calculations.

Answer (score 1):

Financial calculations should be carried out using the Decimal datatype. Doubles store 'approximations' of the specified number since the specified number can't be stored perfectly within the specified bit-allocation.

Answer (score 1):

`0.099999999999999978` and `0.1` don't differ by a factor of 10, they are almost the same. Just like 0.999 is almost 1.

But you really should use `Decimal` instead of `Double` for financial calculations. `Double` can't exactly represent numbers like `0.1` whereas `Decimal` can. (On the other hand neither can represent 1/3 exactly).

Additionally `Decimal` has a larger mantissa and throws exceptions when overflows occur.

Answer (score 1):

Please use decimal for monetary calculations.

Have a look [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165761/decimal-vs-double-which-one-should-i-use-and-when)