# c# how to check string is a number when using console.readline

Tags: c#, string, console, numbers, console.readline

How would I go by checking if there are number values in a string when using `console.readline`?

```
PlayerNode playerList = new PlayerNode();
for (int x = 1; x <= numPlayers; x++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
    Player Aplayer = new Player();
    Aplayer.Name = Console.ReadLine();
    playerList.AddPlayer(Aplayer);
    Console.WriteLine("How Much money do you want to play with?");
    Aplayer.Winnings = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());// How would i change this to check for number values?        
}
```

Comment: Next time use google ! Write this in google:c# how to check string is a number.

Answer (score 1):

It will not go to the next statement until a number is typed into the console.

```
        Console.WriteLine("How much money do you want to play with?");
        bool itsNumeric = false;
        double money;

        while(itsNumeric == false)
        {
            itsNumeric = double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine().ToString(), out money);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

[`Decimal.TryParse(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ew0seb73(v=vs.110).aspx)

Usage:

```
decimal result;
if (Decimal.TryParse(str, NumberStyles.Number | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol,
                     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
{
    // ...
}
```

---

Don't use floats for financial values. [Where is the floating point problem in this C# financial calculation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5787991/where-is-the-floating-point-problem-in-this-c-sharp-financial-calculation)

Comment: He's using `float`s, not `int`s. And please try to avoid answering obvious duplicates.